# Mongo DB BsonSerializationException when using IAggregateFluentExtensions.GraphLookup() with GUIDs

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I am storing trees of nodes in a (local) Mongo database, using GUIDs as the EntityId and ParentEntityId for each node. I am trying to retrieve nodes using IAggregateFluentExtensions.GraphLookup(). The call to GraphLookup() is throwing:

> MongoDB.Bson.BsonSerializationException : GuidSerializer cannot deserialize a Guid when GuidRepresentation is Unspecified.

Why is it throwing this exception? GUID handling is configured for V3, per the code below. It has been working for storing & retrieving other types in the same database that have GUIDs on them.

Here is my Entity class for each Node:

```
public class TestEntity
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set;}

    [BsonGuidRepresentation(GuidRepresentation.Standard)]
    public Guid EntityId { get; set; }

    [BsonGuidRepresentation(GuidRepresentation.Standard)]
    public Guid ParentEntityId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Here is a simplified version of the repository code, which throws the exception, on the GraphLookup() line.

```
public async Task<List<object>> DoGraphLookup()
{
    BsonDefaults.GuidRepresentationMode = GuidRepresentationMode.V3;
    BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(new GuidSerializer(GuidRepresentation.Standard));

    MongoClientSettings mongoClientSettings = MongoClientSettings.FromConnectionString("mongodb://HOSTNAME:27017");
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(mongoClientSettings);

    IMongoDatabase database = mongoClient.GetDatabase("DATABASENAME");

    IMongoCollection<TestEntity> collection = database.GetCollection<TestEntity>("COLLECTIONNAME");

    List<object> result = await collection
        .Aggregate()
        //.Match(c => c.Name == "MatchName")
        .GraphLookup<TestEntity, Guid, Guid, Guid, TestEntity, IEnumerable<TestEntity>, object>(
        from: collection,
        startWith: $"${nameof(TestEntity.EntityId)}",
        connectFromField: nameof(TestEntity.ParentEntityId),
        connectToField: nameof(TestEntity.EntityId),
        @as: "BreadCrumb",
        depthField: "order")
        .ToListAsync();

    return result;
}
```

I'm using C# .NET Core 3.1, with these Nuget packages in my project:

```
MongoDB.Bson 2.13.1
MongoDB.Driver 2.13.1
MongoDB.Driver.Core 2.13.1
```

DB Looks like this:

[Database contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OZ7l.png)

--- EDIT ---
Exception stack trace:

> MyApplication.Repositories.TreeOfNodesRepository.DoGraphLookup:
> Outcome: Failed
> Error Message:
> MongoDB.Bson.BsonSerializationException : GuidSerializer cannot deserialize a Guid when GuidRepresentation is Unspecified.
> Stack Trace:
> at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.GuidSerializer.Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
> at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.IBsonSerializerExtensions.Deserialize[TValue](IBsonSerializer`1 serializer, BsonDeserializationContext context) at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.ObjectSerializer.Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args) at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.IBsonSerializerExtensions.Deserialize[TValue](IBsonSerializer`1 serializer, BsonDeserializationContext context)
> at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.DynamicDocumentBaseSerializer`1.Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args) at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.SerializerBase`1.MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.IBsonSerializer.Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
> at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.ObjectSerializer.DeserializeDiscriminatedValue(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
> at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.ObjectSerializer.Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
> at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.IBsonSerializerExtensions.Deserialize[TValue](IBsonSerializer`1 serializer, BsonDeserializationContext context) at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.EnumerableSerializerBase`2.Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
> at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.IBsonSerializerExtensions.Deserialize[TValue](IBsonSerializer`1 serializer, BsonDeserializationContext context) at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.AggregateOperation`1.CursorDeserializer.Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
> at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.IBsonSerializerExtensions.Deserialize[TValue](IBsonSerializer`1 serializer, BsonDeserializationContext context) at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.AggregateOperation`1.AggregateResultDeserializer.Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
> at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.IBsonSerializerExtensions.Deserialize[TValue](IBsonSerializer`1 serializer, BsonDeserializationContext context) at MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandUsingCommandMessageWireProtocol`1.ProcessResponse(ConnectionId connectionId, CommandMessage responseMessage)
> at MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandUsingCommandMessageWireProtocol`1.ExecuteAsync(IConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.Server.ServerChannel.ExecuteProtocolAsync[TResult](IWireProtocol`1 protocol, ICoreSession session, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.RetryableReadOperationExecutor.ExecuteAsync[TResult](IRetryableReadOperation`1 operation, RetryableReadContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.ReadCommandOperation`1.ExecuteAsync(RetryableReadContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.AggregateOperation`1.ExecuteAsync(RetryableReadContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.AggregateOperation`1.ExecuteAsync(IReadBinding binding, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at MongoDB.Driver.OperationExecutor.ExecuteReadOperationAsync[TResult](IReadBinding binding, IReadOperation`1 operation, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.ExecuteReadOperationAsync[TResult](IClientSessionHandle session, IReadOperation`1 operation, ReadPreference readPreference, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.AggregateAsync[TResult](IClientSessionHandle session, PipelineDefinition`2 pipeline, AggregateOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.UsingImplicitSessionAsync[TResult](Func`2 funcAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at MongoDB.Driver.IAsyncCursorSourceExtensions.ToListAsync[TDocument](IAsyncCursorSource`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at MyApplication.Repositories.TreeOfNodesRepository.DoGraphLookup() in c:\Source\saasem\CodeGenerator\Tests\CodeGenerator.ApplicationStore.Tests\Repositories\GraphcLookupTest.cs:line 45
> at NUnit.Framework.Internal.TaskAwaitAdapter.GenericAdapter`1.BlockUntilCompleted() at NUnit.Framework.Internal.MessagePumpStrategy.NoMessagePumpStrategy.WaitForCompletion(AwaitAdapter awaiter) at NUnit.Framework.Internal.AsyncToSyncAdapter.Await(Func`1 invoke)
> at NUnit.Framework.Internal.Commands.TestMethodCommand.RunTestMethod(TestExecutionContext context)
> at NUnit.Framework.Internal.Commands.TestMethodCommand.Execute(TestExecutionContext context)
> at NUnit.Framework.Internal.Execution.SimpleWorkItem.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.b__0()
> at NUnit.Framework.Internal.ContextUtils.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`1.<DoIsolated>b__0(Object _) at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) --- End of stack trace from previous location --- at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) at NUnit.Framework.Internal.ContextUtils.DoIsolated(ContextCallback callback, Object state) at NUnit.Framework.Internal.ContextUtils.DoIsolated[T](Func`1 func)
> at NUnit.Framework.Internal.Execution.SimpleWorkItem.PerformWork()

Comment: DB looks like this:

Comment: A stack trace might help others to find a solution to your problem.

Comment: Thanks Richard, I've added the exception stack trace.